# Sorting data. Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

Looking for advise on how to solve the following problem.

I have Pandas dataframe, let's say 1.000.000 rows by 10 columns (A, B, C...J). Data type is float.

The task is to remove all the rows (i) in a dataframe if there exist another raw (j) with all values equal to or greater than values in original raw (i).

```
(Ai<=Aj) and (Bi<=Bj) and (Ci<=Cj) ... and (Ji<=Jj)
```

I wonder whether there any tools exist in pandas tool kit or any other analytics python module to efficiently solve this problem.

I have a very inefficient solution with multiple iterations in a simple array. Hoping to find smth more promising.

Simplified example, original data:

```
    0 1 5 4 4 2
    2 5 6 4 3 7
   -2 5 6 5 3 7
    0 0 0 0 0 1
    0 0 0 0 0 8
```

Result to be:

```
 0 1 5 4 4 2
 2 5 6 4 3 7
-2 5 6 5 3 7
 0 0 0 0 0 8
```

Comment: Can you provide the code to your "inefficient solution"?

Comment: I will add the code a bit later (need to clean up), but basically it is a loop in the loop algorithm. I go through all the rows (1.000.000 rows) and every time compare chosen row with 999 999 remaining rows. If I find rows with all the values equal to or smaller than in the chosen raw, then these rows are marked. At the end, all the marked rows are removed. If I'm not mistaken, I have about 10^12 iterations. It takes hours to go through all the rows. Super  inefficient solution :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a way from `numpy`

```
#import numpy as np
df[np.any(np.sum(df.values>=df.values[:,None],1)==1,1)]
Out[40]: 
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  0  1  5  4  4  2
1  2  5  6  4  3  7
2 -2  5  6  5  3  7
4  0  0  0  0  0  8
```

Comment: Thanks for advise. Could you explain it a bit? What is the difference between **df.values** and **df.values[:,None]**. Whats does **None** do here?

Comment: @alexnord that is numpy broadcast , with trigger onerow from df get different for whole dataframe

Comment: .@Wen, I have tried another data input, and it seems the algo doesn't work correctly...  
[[ 0,  1,  5,  4,  4,  2],
       [ 2,  5,  6,  4,  3,  7],
       [-2,  5,  6,  5,  3,  7],
       [0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  8], 
       [11, 10, 10, 10, 10,  7],
       [12, 10, 10, 10, 10,  7],
       [13, 10, 10, 10, 10,  7]]

Comment: Result for the case above should be [[0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  8],[13, 10, 10, 10, 10,  7]]

Comment: @alexnord updated `df[np.any(np.sum(df.values>=df.values[:,None],1)==1,1)]
`

Comment: .@Wen - many thanks. It took me few hours to understand the last one-line code...Starting new jorney now :) One more question please. Is it possible to exclude some of the columns from the analysis? I still want all the columns to be at the resultant array, but want to apply the rule only to specific columns (such as B, D, F for instance)

Comment: @alexnord doing df[['B','E','C']].values instead of df.values